# virtual box linix try to run buildozer

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer, kivymd

i have create an application in kivy with python and i would like it to run it to my phone.i use virtual box because i have window and is need Linux to run buildozer every time i run buildozer android debug i  am facing an error. please if you can help me to solve that issue it will be very helpful thank here is the error i am facing:

```
RAN: /usr/bin/bash -c 'venv/bin/pip install Cython'

  STDOUT:
Ignoring "sys._home = value" override
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Collecting Cython
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/cython/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/cython/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/cython/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/cython/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/cython/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/cython/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/cython/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Cython (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for Cython
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping


  STDERR:

# Command failed: /usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=myapp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3,kivy,kivymd,request,json --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/home/nikolas/Desktop/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a" --ndk-api=21 --ignore-setup-py
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     SESSION_MANAGER = 'local/nikolas-VirtualBox:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/10190,unix/nikolas-VirtualBox:/tmp/.ICE-unix/10190'
#     QT_ACCESSIBILITY = '1'
#     COLORTERM = 'truecolor'
#     XDG_CONFIG_DIRS = '/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg'
#     XDG_MENU_PREFIX = 'gnome-'
#     GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID = 'this-is-deprecated'
#     LC_ADDRESS = 'el_CY.UTF-8'
#     GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE = 'ubuntu'
#     LC_NAME = 'el_CY.UTF-8'
#     SSH_AUTH_SOCK = '/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh'
#     XMODIFIERS = '@im=ibus'
#     DESKTOP_SESSION = 'ubuntu'
#     LC_MONETARY = 'el_CY.UTF-8'
#     SSH_AGENT_PID = '10136'
#     GTK_MODULES = 'gail:atk-bridge'
#     DBUS_STARTER_BUS_TYPE = 'session'
#     PWD = '/home/nikolas/Desktop/app'
#     LOGNAME = 'nikolas'
#     XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP = 'ubuntu'
#     XDG_SESSION_TYPE = 'x11'
#     GPG_AGENT_INFO = '/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1'
#     XAUTHORITY = '/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority'
#     WINDOWPATH = '2'
#     HOME = '/home/nikolas'
#     USERNAME = 'nikolas'
#     IM_CONFIG_PHASE = '1'
#     LC_PAPER = 'el_CY.UTF-8'
#     LANG = 'en_US.UTF-8'
#     LS_COLORS = 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'
#     XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = 'ubuntu:GNOME'
#     VTE_VERSION = '6003'
#     GNOME_TERMINAL_SCREEN = '/org/gnome/Terminal/screen/3ed57b1d_183a_41a6_b208_86d5eaaecacd'
#     INVOCATION_ID = '6cc2157827fc437e8c2ca1e121d1a6a9'
#     MANAGERPID = '9924'
#     LESSCLOSE = '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s'
#     XDG_SESSION_CLASS = 'user'
#     TERM = 'xterm-256color'
#     LC_IDENTIFICATION = 'el_CY.UTF-8'
#     LESSOPEN = '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s'
#     USER = 'nikolas'
#     GNOME_TERMINAL_SERVICE = ':1.114'
#     DISPLAY = ':0'
#     SHLVL = '1'
#     LC_TELEPHONE = 'el_CY.UTF-8'
#     QT_IM_MODULE = 'ibus'
#     LC_MEASUREMENT = 'el_CY.UTF-8'
#     DBUS_STARTER_ADDRESS = 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus,guid=b35277c3b5d6fe636ff13366602a4036'
#     XDG_RUNTIME_DIR = '/run/user/1000'
#     LC_TIME = 'el_CY.UTF-8'
#     JOURNAL_STREAM = '8:37568'
#     XDG_DATA_DIRS = '/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop'
#     PATH = '/home/nikolas/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/home/nikolas/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin'
#     GDMSESSION = 'ubuntu'
#     DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS = 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus,guid=b35277c3b5d6fe636ff13366602a4036'
#     LC_NUMERIC = 'el_CY.UTF-8'
#     _ = '/usr/local/bin/buildozer'
#     OLDPWD = '/home/nikolas/Desktop'
#     PACKAGES_PATH = '/home/nikolas/.buildozer/android/packages'
#     ANDROIDSDK = '/home/nikolas/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
#     ANDROIDNDK = '/home/nikolas/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c'
#     ANDROIDAPI = '27'
#     ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are missing `libssl-dev`. Just open your terminal and run the command `sudo apt install libssl-dev`. You might have missed the buildozer dependencies. So even after installing `libssl-dev` you get error then try running the following command:

```
sudo apt install -y git zip unzip openjdk-8-jdk python3-pip autoconf libtool pkg-config zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev libtinfo5 cmake libffi-dev libssl-dev
pip3 install --upgrade Cython==0.29.19 virtualenv
```

Comment: have you re-runned buildozer after deleting .buildozer directory?

Comment: still, i delete buildozer and still getting the error

Comment: Well, see the error you showed in your question should be resolved by this. Still, you getting same error?? Are you sure it's `same`??

Comment: now is working but when the application opens it crush

Comment: There might be missing requirements or something then. Use logcat for that